# Why I'm not getting the updated array in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

I'm having an array named `$questions` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 33185
            [question_parent_id] => 0
            [question_subject_id] => 4
            [question_topic_id] => 503
            [question_directions] => 
            [question_text] => Two gases are at 300 K and 350 K respectively Ratio of average kinetic energy of their molecules is
            [question_file] => 
            [question_description] => 
            [question_difficulty_type] => 1
            [question_has_sub_ques] => 0
            [question_picked_individually] => no
            [question_appeared_count] => 0
            [question_manual] => 0
            [question_site_id] => 
            [question_created_staff_id] => fbfee12504bf3c4a038d4c9f142f894e
            [question_added_date] => 1328180210
            [question_updated_staff_id] => 
            [question_updated_date] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 33187
            [question_parent_id] => 0
            [question_subject_id] => 4
            [question_topic_id] => 503
            [question_directions] => 
            [question_text] => what will be the temperature when the rms velocity is double the rms velocity at 300 K
            [question_file] => 
            [question_description] => 
            [question_difficulty_type] => 1
            [question_has_sub_ques] => 0
            [question_picked_individually] => no
            [question_appeared_count] => 0
            [question_manual] => 0
            [question_site_id] => 
            [question_created_staff_id] => fbfee12504bf3c4a038d4c9f142f894e
            [question_added_date] => 1328180274
            [question_updated_staff_id] => 
            [question_updated_date] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 33188
            [question_parent_id] => 0
            [question_subject_id] => 4
            [question_topic_id] => 503
            [question_directions] => 
            [question_text] => a gas at 300 K has pressure 4 × 10-10 N/m 2 If k = 1.38 × 10-23 J/K the number of molecules./ cm3 of the order of
            [question_file] => 
            [question_description] => 
            [question_difficulty_type] => 1
            [question_has_sub_ques] => 0
            [question_picked_individually] => no
            [question_appeared_count] => 0
            [question_manual] => 0
            [question_site_id] => 
            [question_created_staff_id] => fbfee12504bf3c4a038d4c9f142f894e
            [question_added_date] => 1328180400
            [question_updated_staff_id] => 1096ab29ecde5cec198bb2ebe730d229
            [question_updated_date] => 1338272917
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 33190
            [question_parent_id] => 0
            [question_subject_id] => 4
            [question_topic_id] => 503
            [question_directions] => 
            [question_text] => The rms speed of oxygen molecules at a certain temperature is v if the temperature is doubled and the oxygen gas dissociates into atomic oxygen, the rms speed would be
            [question_file] => 
            [question_description] => 
            [question_difficulty_type] => 1
            [question_has_sub_ques] => 0
            [question_picked_individually] => no
            [question_appeared_count] => 0
            [question_manual] => 0
            [question_site_id] => 
            [question_created_staff_id] => fbfee12504bf3c4a038d4c9f142f894e
            [question_added_date] => 1328180486
            [question_updated_staff_id] => 1096ab29ecde5cec198bb2ebe730d229
            [question_updated_date] => 1338273032
        )
)
```

I've written following code to update an array. But after completion of foreach loop execution if I print the array $questions then I'm not getting the updated array. I'm getting the original array instead. Can anyone guide me in this regard to resolve my issue? Any help would be highly appreciated. For your reference following is my array update code:

```
$sql  = " SELECT * FROM ".TBL_QUESTIONS." WHERE question_subject_id=".$subject_id;
            $sql .= " AND question_topic_id=".$topic_id;

            $this->mDb->Query($sql);
            $questions = $this->mDb->FetchArray();

    $exclude_words = array('at','is','are','when','whom');

                foreach($questions as $arr) {
            foreach($exclude_words as $excluding) {

                $str_start_pos = strpos($arr['question_text'], $excluding);

                if($str_start_pos >= 0) {

                  if($str_start_pos != 0)  
                  $excluding = " ".$excluding;

                    $excluding = $excluding." ";
                $arr['question_text'] = str_replace($excluding, "", $arr['question_text']);

              }
            }
          }

          print_d($questions);
```

Comment: place an echo or die inside condition "if($str_start_pos >= 0) {" to check if its ever getting inside or not.

Comment: Because you did not understand the answer on your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189889/how-to-remove-few-strings-from-each-associative-array-element-containing-a-strin Go read all the comments and look at the examples. For one, arrays are not passed by reference. And second, you don't want to go through your big array twice (performance) so its better to not actually change your array, but to process it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$questions is not passed by reference into $arr. Therefore you must explicitly update $questions on each loop

```
foreach($questions as $index=>$arr) {
            foreach($exclude_words as $excluding) {
                $str_start_pos = strpos($arr['question_text'], $excluding);
                if($str_start_pos >= 0) {
                    if($str_start_pos != 0)  $excluding = " ".$excluding;
                    $excluding = $excluding." ";
                    $arr['question_text'] = str_replace($excluding, "", $arr['question_text']);
                    $questions[$index]['question_text']=$arr['question_text'];
              }
            }
        }
```

that's a quick'n dirty solution. I believe it would be more ellegant to explode $question by space, and perform an array diff to get the elements in $questions_array that don't fall within the $exclude_words array. In the end you implode the clean array using space as the glue.

```
foreach($questions as $index=>$arr) {
    $questions_array = explode(' ',$arr['question_text']);
    $clean_questions = array_diff($questions_array, $exclude_words);
    $questions[$index]['question_text'] = implode(' ',$clean_questions );
}
```

Comment: :Thank you so much for your immense help. Upvoted and accepted the answer

Comment: I haz So much reputation now ToT

Comment: Simpler is to do `foreach($questions as &$arr) {`. The & makes it a reference.